# Android animate view mask from top to bottom

Tags: android, animation, view, mask

I have created custom view which is parent of FrameLayout.
Inside my view I have created the mask:

```
function makeBitmapMask(int animationHeight) {
    mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(),
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);
    drawable.setBounds(0, animationHeight, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
}
```

and created Paint:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setXfermode(mPorterDuffXferMode);
```

Then I have override dispatchDraw:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        paint.setXfermode(mPorterDuffXferMode);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0.0f, 0.0f, mPaint);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

To make mask animation I run Handler:

```
int animationHeight = 0;
private void animateView() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animateView();
                animationHeight += 10;
                makeBitmapMask(animationHeight);
                invalidate();
            }
        }, 10);
    }
```

It works, but very slow.

The same result using ValueAnimator:

```
ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, getHeight());
    int mDuration = 3000;
    va.setDuration(mDuration);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            makeBitmapMask(value);
            invalidate();
        }
    });

    va.start();
```

I think, that makeBitmapMask() is very slow.
Maybe I can only change mask bounds, or height, without recreating new Bitmap on the every animation frame?
What is the right way to make animation of view mask?

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`

Comment: It's slow anyway. I think, that makeBitmapMask() is very slow. Maybe I can only change mask bounds, or height, without recreating new Bitmap on the every animation frame?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use circular reveal. Just set the animation's source point very far away and animate it between a very large radius to a little bit larger radius, it's a little hacky, but it can result with an almost straight-line reveal.